# Azure Synapse - Dataflow fails when using API request body

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I used "copy data" activity with following request body:

```
{
  "query": "query RoomStays($first: Int!, $from: Date!, $to: Date!, $after: String) {\n  room_stays(\n    first: $first,\n    filter: {\n      reservation_from: { ge: $from },\n      reservation_to: { le: $to }\n    },\n    after: $after\n  ) {\n    pageInfo {\n      hasNextPage\n      endCursor\n    }\n    edges {\n      cursor\n      node {\n        check_in\n        check_out\n        gross\n        lodgingsGross\n        additionalSales\n        reservation_from\n        reservation_to\n        category {\n          name\n        }\n        reservation {\n          createdAt\n          bookingChannelCode\n          stayType {\n          \tname\n        \t}\n          client {\n            country\n          }\n          bookingSource {\n            name\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}",
  "variables": {
    "after": "null",
    "from": "2000-01-01",
    "to": "2100-01-01",
    "first": 100
  },
  "operationName": "RoomStays"
}
```

[Copy Data Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJBlw.png)

It works without any issues.

Now I am trying to replicate this with the "Dataflow" activity:

I basically just stringyfied it:

```
'{"query": "query RoomStays($first: Int!, $from: Date!, $to: Date!, $after: String) {\n  room_stays(\n    first: $first,\n    filter: {\n      reservation_from: { ge: $from },\n      reservation_to: { le: $to }\n    },\n    after: $after\n  ) {\n    pageInfo {\n      hasNextPage\n      endCursor\n    }\n    edges {\n      cursor\n      node {\n        check_in\n        check_out\n        gross\n        lodgingsGross\n        additionalSales\n        reservation_from\n        reservation_to\n        category {\n          name\n        }\n        reservation {\n          createdAt\n          bookingChannelCode\n          stayType {\n          \tname\n        \t}\n          client {\n            country\n          }\n          bookingSource {\n            name\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}","variables": {"after": null,"from": "2000-01-01","to": "2025-01-01","first": 10},"operationName": "RoomStays"}'
```

[Dataflow Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMp0Q.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIpg1.png)

What could be the reason for failure?
I tried turning "Format" from JSON to None, but that didnt change anything.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/87405#issuecomment-1483680452)

You need to create a column, then an external call.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).